# How to switch between transparant UINavigationBar and UINavigationBar with backgroundColor

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a few `UIViewControllers` which all have a solid backgroundColor. However, on the profile of a user, I want to show a blurred profile image on the background, so I need a transparant `UINavigationBar`. This works great. The way I do it is as follows:

All my `UIViewControllers` are set to have a transparant UINavigationBar like so:

```
    navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
```

Then I simply add a "fake" bar by simply creating a rectangular `UIView` and pinning all edges to where the `UINavigationBar` would be, resulting in the same look but allowing me to have the profile pages transparent. However, I now have a situation where I need to use the "real" `UINavigationBar`, because in my current approach, when I show the keyboard and animate `view.frame.origin.y` to make the screen move up, it goes "over" this fake `UINavigationBar`.

I have therefor set the `barTintColor` property of the `UINavigationBar` in this viewController. Problem occurs when I first go to this view and then to a profile page: it is still the same solid color. The problem does not happen when I go to a profile page after launch directly.

[This is the desired result, which I can see when I go directly to a profile page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkjQK.png)

[This is what a normal viewController looks like, with the "fake" UINavigationBar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKiD2.png)

[And this is the error. This happens when I first go to the viewController with the barTintColor set, and then to a profile page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKo7m.png)

Any tips on how I can fix this? I have tried "resetting" the `UINavigationBar` properties in `viewWillDisappear` of the viewController with the `barTintColor` set, but this didn't work:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {

    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = nil

}
```

Might be useful: I use pushes transition most of the time (between the relevant viewControllers definitely). Only use present to show popups or similar. Everything in code - no storyboards.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Quick thought - have you tried subclassing `UINavigationController`? I've done this (subclassing) for a completely different reason and it works well. Maybe it could help you in this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Present in stead of Push. So you can have two differents navigation bar.